# Plot periodic trajectories

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have some data of a particle moving in a corridor with closed boundary conditions.
Plotting the trajectory leads to a zig-zag trajectory.

[image]

I would like to know how to prevent `plot()` from connecting the points where the particle comes back to the start. Some thing like in the upper part of the pic, but without `"."`

The first idea I had was to find the index where the `numpy` array `a[:-1]-a[1:]` becomes positive and then plot from 0 to that index. But how would I get the index of the first occurrence of a positive element of `a[:-1]-a[1:]`?
Maybe there are some other ideas.

Comment: There is a lot to be said for just not connecting the data points.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd go a different approach. First, I'd determine the jump points not by looking at the sign of the derivative, as probably the movement might go up or down, or even have some periodicity in it. I'd look at those points with the biggest derivative.

Second, an elegant approach to have breaks in a plot line is to mask one value on each jump. Then matplotlib will make segments automatically. My code is:

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

xs = np.linspace(0., 100., 1000.)
data = (xs*0.03 + np.sin(xs) * 0.1) % 1

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(xs, data, "r-")

#Make a masked array with jump points masked
abs_d_data = np.abs(np.diff(data))
mask = np.hstack([ abs_d_data > abs_d_data.mean()+3*abs_d_data.std(), [False]])
masked_data = np.ma.MaskedArray(data, mask)
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(xs, masked_data, "b-")

plt.show()
```

And gives us as result:
[image]

The disadvantage of course is that you lose one point at each break - but with the sampling rate you seem to have I guess you can trade this in for simpler code.

Comment: +1) -- I learned a very elegant use case for masked array in matplotlib

Comment: I found a case where this solution fails. It is the case where the trajectory has no breaks in it. My fix was just to check the std if it is larger than some minimum (ad-hoc chosed).

Answer (score 3):

To find where the particle has crossed the upper boundary, you can do something like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.linspace(0, 10, 50) % 5
>>> a = np.linspace(0, 10, 50) % 5 # some sample data
>>> np.nonzero(np.diff(a) < 0)[0] + 1
array([25, 49])
>>> a[24:27]
array([ 4.89795918,  0.10204082,  0.30612245])
>>> a[48:]
array([ 4.79591837,  0.        ])
>>>
```

`np.diff(a)` calculates the discrete difference of `a`, while `np.nonzero` finds where the condition `np.diff(a) < 0` is negative, i.e., the particle has moved downward.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Thorsten Kranz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14358909/15330539) a version which adds points to the original data when the 'y' crosses the period. This is important if the density of data-points isn't very high, e.g. `np.linspace(0., 100., 100)` vs. the original `np.linspace(0., 100., 1000)`. The `x` position of the curve transitions are linear interpolated. Wrapped up in a function its:

```py
import numpy as np
def periodic2plot(x, y, period=np.pi*2.):
    indexes = np.argwhere(np.abs(np.diff(y))>.5*period).flatten()
    index_shift = 0
    for i in indexes:
        i += index_shift
        index_shift += 3  # in every loop it adds 3 elements

        if y[i] > .5*period:
            x_transit = np.interp(period, np.unwrap(y[i:i+2], period=period), x[i:i+2])
            add = np.ma.array([ period, 0., 0.], mask=[0,1,0])
        else:
            # interpolate needs sorted xp = np.unwrap(y[i:i+2], period=period)
            x_transit = np.interp(0, np.unwrap(y[i:i+2], period=period)[::-1], x[i:i+2][::-1])
            add = np.ma.array([ 0., 0., period], mask=[0,1,0])
        x_add = np.ma.array([x_transit]*3, mask=[0,1,0])

        x = np.ma.hstack((x[:i+1], x_add, x[i+1:]))
        y = np.ma.hstack((y[:i+1], add, y[i+1:]))
    return x, y
```

The code for comparison to the original answer of [Thorsten Kranz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14358909/15330539) with lower data-points density.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0., 100., 100)
y = (x*0.03 + np.sin(x) * 0.1) % 1

#Thorsten Kranz: Make a masked array with jump points masked
abs_d_data = np.abs(np.diff(y))
mask = np.hstack([np.abs(np.diff(y))>.5, [False]])
masked_y = np.ma.MaskedArray(y, mask)

# Plot
plt.figure()
plt.plot(*periodic2plot(x, y, period=1), label='This answer')
plt.plot(x, masked_y, label='Thorsten Kranz')

plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=True)
plt.legend(loc=1)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the connecting line you will have to plot by segments.

Here's a quick way to plot by segments when the derivative of `a` changes sign:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.linspace(0, 20, 50) % 5  # similar to Micheal's sample data
x = np.arange(50)  # x scale

indices = np.where(np.diff(a) < 0)[0] + 1  # the same as Micheal's np.nonzero
for n, i in enumerate(indices):
    if n == 0:
        plot(x[:i], a[:i], 'b-')
    else:
        plot(x[indices[n - 1]:i], a[indices[n - 1]:i], 'b-')
```

[image]