# Matplotlib remove interpolation for missing data

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, scatter-plot

I am plotting timeseries data using Matplotlib and some of the data is missing in the sequence. Matplotlib implicitly **joins** the last contiguous data point to the next one. But in case data is missing, the plot looks ugly. The following is the plot obtained.
[image]

It can be seen that near the April 30th marker, data is missing and Matplotlib joins the points.
Also the following image is the scatter plot of the data. Scatter plot covers up this fault, but then contiguous data points won't be joint in this case. Moreover, scatter plot is very slow given the huge number of data points involved.
[image]

What is the recommended solution for such problems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can identify where the break points should be you can either:

1. break the data and plot each 'section' by hand
2. insert `np.nan` in the data in the gaps

See for example [Plot periodic trajectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357104/plot-periodic-trajectories).

You can get the same effect of `scatter` (if you don't want to scale the size or color of each point independently) with

```
ax.plot(x, y, linestyle='none', marker='o')
```

Comment: Ended up using Pandas which would insert NaN

Comment: @NipunBatra If you did something different you should write that up as an answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

As the previous answer says, you should insert NaNs where there is no data. **This answer is specific to Pandas**, and explains how this can be achieved easily. Either :

- `Series.resample()`  or
- `Series.reindex()`

The simplest method to use is `resample()`. This is the most concise way for regularly spaced data. So in your example above, if you have e.g. 5 minute data, just do `data.resample("5 min")`. This will return your data set with 'NaT' (time equivalent of NaN) in the missing values.

The only case where this doesn't work too well is when your samples are not regularly-spaced.

The alternative is `reindex()`, which also works for ordered (but non-time-series) data. So for example, if you had a data set indexed with integers from 0 .. 100, but with a few missing samples, you could do `data.reindex([0:100])`. You can also replicate the behaviour of `resample` with `reindex`, by passing in a `pandas.date_range()` function as an argument.