# Plotting GroupBy Object in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with various parameters (continuous time-series data) and other columns to filter out various conditions; these are made up of `1` when the condition is true and `NaN` when the condition is false.

If I plot a parameter and then plot it again just in the gate, I can do:

```
df.parameter.plot()
df.groupby('filter_column').parameter.plot(style='bo')
```

This example works fine, but if I want to plot using a line (`style='b-'` for example) it then joins the groups of filtered data with a line

A work-around is to create intermediate series, or multiply the two columns within a matplotlib call:

```
series = df.parameter * df.filter_column
series.plot(style='b-')

plt.plot(df.parameter * df.filter_column,'b-')
```

I'm not a fan of this type of plot statement or creating the intermediate columns. It would be really useful to have the direct `groupby` line plot deal with the NAs in the same way as a series.

Does anyone have any more elegant workarounds for this?

Comment: Could you include an image of the two graphs?

Comment: No really - but it's the same issue as the second plot in this post - i.e. the group-by plotting does not treat a gap between data in the same way as discontinuous data in a Dataframe column or a series, and this seems inconsistent. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258656/how-to-plot-a-sparse-with-gaps-line-with-its-segments-colored-according-to-som

Comment: I may not be visualizing correctly, but this post has two options ("linestyle=None" or resampling) that may be useful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454183/matplotlib-remove-interpolation-for-missing-data

Comment: It's fine if it's a column - the gaps are NaN and it plots correctly - the issue is specifically using groupby